# Add a custom sort by location on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-code

Im working on a new classified ad website based on wordpress and theme i bought which is Adifier does not have sort my location. So i want to add on search result also this new custom sort.

The logic is that i have to get location based user gps firstly from Geolocation API then pass this parameters on query that sort ads by nearest location. What about to calculate distance with Vincenty formula?

Help me to build logic behind that also if it is possible any sample code then can i modify to achieve this task.